# Raspberry Pi: current sensor ACS724 noisy output

Tags: analog, raspberry-pi, current-measurement

My goal is to build a DC current sensing device with a sample rate of 5k - 10ksamples/sec @ 0-2 A. The intention is to be able to evaluate various 10-24 V DC devices in order to determine Wh consumed over different workloads/configurations.

The test setup would typically be that we'd have a bench DC power supply providing a consistent voltage - so I think we'd just need to measure current. The idea would be to log the data over a ~24 hour period and do some sort of averaging/integration to get a reasonably accurate picture of total power consumption over that sort of time period.

My current setup looks like:

Raspberry Pi 4B --> (via spi) RaspIO Analog Zero --> ACS724

The [ACS724](https://www.allegromicro.com/%7E/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS724-Datasheet.ashx) is in a PCB form factor, designed for a ±5 A range. Googling "ACS724 Current Sensor Carrier -5A to +5A" will show what these look like. These units should vary the output signal by 400mV/A, centred on 2.5 V. So 0 A should provide a 2.5 V output, and +1 A should provide a 2.9 V output.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I'm noticing that the voltage input is varing a lot more than I expected. With the 12 V source disconnected from the ACS724, I am seeing these sorts of measurements (sample rate of 5 samples/s):

```
2.39399v = 0.26502a
2.40044v = 0.24890a
2.41656v = 0.20860a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.42623v = 0.18442a
2.42623v = 0.18442a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.42946v = 0.17636a
2.42946v = 0.17636a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.43591v = 0.16023a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.41334v = 0.21666a
```

And with the 12 V switchmode power supply via a 100 Ω resistor (expecting ~120 mA which should translate to 2.5 V + 0.048 V = 2.548 V output)

```
2.41979v = 0.20054a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.41979v = 0.20054a
2.41656v = 0.20860a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.41656v = 0.20860a
2.41979v = 0.20054a
2.41334v = 0.21666a
2.41656v = 0.20860a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.41979v = 0.20054a
2.41656v = 0.20860a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.42301v = 0.19248a
2.41979v = 0.20054a
2.41979v = 0.20054a
```

This output seems unusably noisy. I can accept that the reference 5 V voltage is probably not exactly 5 V from the RPI, so perhaps I need to calibrate it to find a new centre voltage. However, even with no input current, the voltage I'm seeing from the ACS724 has a lot of variance.

I've tried adding a 4.7 nF capacitor to the "filter" pins on the ACS724 board, but it doesn't seem to have changed the result in any obvious way.

The RaspIO Analog Zero seems to be reporting otherwise accurate and stable voltages. I tested this with a simple voltage divider circuit on the 5 V rail of the Raspberry Pi, and it reported 2.5 V with no more than 0.0032 V of variance over 100k samples.

I'm stumped. This is my first real electronics project and I'm not really sure what to try next - other than trying a different current sensor.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switchmode power supplies ("switchers") are usually very noisy and likely have layout guidelines for sticking them on a PCB, depending on how you've physically placed everything in relation to one another you may be picking up a bit of noise from your 12V supply which is messing with your analog reads.

Comment: With the 12V source disconnected the ACS724 is floating and probably picking up mains hum or something. Your 100 ohm load test does not seem so noisy to me, most measurements are within 10mA of each other. There's just a little offset you might have to adjust for.

Comment: In my experience these current sensors are poor at measuring anything but low frequencies. If you need to sense the high-side, they might be useful. But, you should be able to use a simple resistive shunt on the low side for what you are doing.

Comment: _"...to get a reasonably accurate picture of total power consumption"_ - define 'reasonably accurate'. What does the '0.25' next to R1 mean?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ideally within a few percent of actual. The intent is that the measurements will inform sizing of battery systems that need to run the gear for a specific period of time once mains power is lost.

The 0.25 is a default label put in by Fritzing, it's the resistors watt rating in this case. I've actually connected 10x 10ohm resistors in series in my test to deal with the watt limit of the resistors i have on-hand, which should keep it to ~144mW per resistor, under their rated 250mW.

Comment: @snowmanemperor & Unimportant: Thanks, i'll try again with a battery source instead and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Mattman944 Yeah ok, cheers. I'll do some reading on shunts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The RaspIO Analog Zero seems to be reporting otherwise accurate and
> stable voltages. I tested this with a simple voltage divider circuit
> on the 5 V rail of the Raspberry Pi, and it reported 2.5 V with no
> more than 0.0032 V of variance over 100k samples.

The RaspIO Analog Zero module uses an [MCP3008](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21295d.pdf) 10 bit ADC. With a reference input of 3.3 V this gives a resolution of 3.223 mV per count. So your measurement of 'no more than 0.0032 V variance' is what would be expected with a very low noise level (~1 bit quantized noise).

You say the current measurement with ~120 mA going through the ACS724 'seems unusably noisy'. However when we look at the voltages translated back to actual ADC output values...

```
751
752
751
750
752
750
751
749
750
752
751
750
752
752
752
751
751
```

...we see that the variation is only 4 counts, so quantized noise has only gone up by ~1 bit.

So where is the problem? The ADC input spans a range of 0 to 3.3 V, but the current sensor's sensitivity is only 0.4 V/A. So 150 mA is 60 mV, which is only ~19 counts or 1.9% of the ADC's range. At this level those 2 bits of noise look bad, but they are only 1% of 2 A.

In the comments you hoped for an accuracy of 'ideally within a few percent of actual'. The noise level you are getting is well within that spec when referred to the full scale reading of 2 A. If you need higher accuracy at lower currents then there are a few things you can do:-

1. Calibrate zero amps on power up and/or manually.
2. Average the readings over a few samples. This will not significantly affect Wh measurements unless the supply voltage varies greatly during current spikes (and you will be integrating the readings to get Wh anyway so...)
3. Replace the ACS724 with a current shunt and low drift op amp, with bias and gain set to maximize ADC input range. If the power supply and load do not share their grounds with some other circuit then you can put the shunt in the ground (negative) wire, allowing the (ground referenced) op amp output to directly fed the ADC.

In the comments you also say,

> The intent is that the measurements will inform sizing of battery
> systems that need to run the gear for a specific period of time once
> mains power is lost

Mains powered equipment generally doesn't run at very low power, so you probably don't have to measure very low currents with great accuracy. For situations where you do, you could use different sensors or shunts that can be switched or plugged in to cover a wider current range.

An accuracy of 'a few percent' should be more than adequate for sizing battery systems, since the capacity of a battery can vary greatly in ways that are difficult to predict.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess the ADC resolution and read voltage range isn't very well paired with the current sensor to be able to accurately read in the 0-200mA range, which i'd like some good resolution on.

It looks like the AnalogZero allows you to replace the ADC chip with a MCP3208 to get 12 bit resolution, perhaps that's a good option. I've also ordered a Sparkfun ACS723 board that includes an op-amp which might let me more easily utilise the available 10 bit resolution over a better voltage range.

Comment: Also thinking perhaps an INA260 based board might be a better option.

I'll do some reading on Shunt + Op-Amp setups.

Comment: The INA260 looks like a good solution for your application. As usual these days the chips are hard to get, but modules are readily available.